# case class extending trait with abstract type

Tags: scala, traits, case-class

I had a couple of case classes like that:

```
case class Size(id: Long, size: Int)

case class Title(id: Long, title: String)
.
.
.
```

I had like 10 of these with pretty much the same functions. I decided to combine them under a common trait, which led to something like this:

```
trait Property[T]{
    val value: T
}

trait PropertyPair[T]{
   val id: Long
   val prop: Property[T]
}

case class Size(id: Long, prop: Property[Int]) extends PropertyPair[Int] {
    def size: Int = prop.value
}

case class Title(id: Long, prop: Property[String]) extends PropertyPair[String] {
    def title: String = prop.value
}
```

Though the code block above seems to be a good solution, and now I can actually define functions under the `PropertyPair` trait, but the code still smells.

1. I need to include `[T]` three times for every property I add
2. I need to explicitly add property name as an extra function to access it as though it is just a field in the case class.

Now to initialize `Title` i need to write

```
Title(101L, Property("Title"))
```

instead of

```
Title(101L, "Title")
```

For some reason I am sure there is a much more elegant and less error-prone solution then the one I provided.

Comment: What are you trying to get out of the inheritance hierarchy? Are you just doing it because you recognize a similarity or because it actually gives you some functionality somewhere you currently don't have / anticipating new use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 2 levels and can replace `trait` with `abstract class` to make use of its constructor:

```
sealed abstract class Property[T](val prop: T) {
  val id: Long
}

case class Size(id: Long, size: Int) extends Property[Int](size)
case class Title(id: Long, title: String) extends Property[String](title)
```

Each of these cases has an `id` value which is required by the `Property` class, but as you want them to have different names for `prop`, you can just pass them to the `Property` constructor as the `prop` value.

Then it can be used as

```
val size = Size(101L, 42)
val title = Title(202L, "Foo")
```

This is a straightforward solution. For a more general case I would suggest you to do it like this:

```
sealed trait AnyProperty {
  val id: Long

  type Prop
  val prop: Prop
}

sealed abstract class Property[T](
  val prop: T
) extends AnyProperty {
  type Prop = T
}
```

(the rest is the same)

Advantages of this approach are that you can use the top trait to refer to *any* property, for example

```
def foo[P <: AnyProperty](p: P): Long = p.id
foo(size) // 101L
```

Of you can refer to the `Prop` type member, for example

```
def buh[P <: AnyProperty](p: P): P#Prop = p.prop
buh(title) // "Foo"
```

Comment: is it actually a hashtag sign in the last code block?

Comment: one more question: 

Would we need a type protection if buh method was placed inside the Property class?

Comment: Very interesting. I assume with this you could also take an array of AnyProperty and map it to their prop value by passing the buh method then without any trouble, correct?

Comment: @Martee Probably it's just a typo, but to avoid confusion: it's pro**j**ection (to project/select, not to protect). The answer is no, when inside `Property`, you can refer to `Prop` _type member_ directly.

Comment: @JordanCutler There will be a trouble with the return type. If you do `List[AnyProperty](size, title).map(buh)`, you will get `List(42, "Foo")`. But `List` is a homogenuous collection, i.e. all elements have the same type and in this case it will be derived to `Any` (lowest common supertype of `Int` and `String`). This is probably fine for you, but then you don't need any type projections, just make `buh` return `Any`.